# Restoring missing DLLs asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll

I had an asp.net website project with some missing DLL files. I found the DLLs and added them back into the "Lib" folder which sits one level above may main project, however within my aspx code if I type "using CMS.Base" I get a not found.

I looked in the .proj file and I can see:

```
<Reference Include="CMS.Base, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=834b12a258f213f9">
  <HintPath>..\Lib\CMS.Base.dll</HintPath>
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
</Reference>
```

Is there something else I should be looking at?

C

Comment: Do you see it in the references?

Comment: No they not in there, just added them using the browse button and errors gone down

Comment: Should I be referencing the "lib" folder automatically some way instead of just picking the individual DLLs?

Comment: No you need to do each individually.